How can I change the upper part of a straight cloth into a circular shape?
I made a curtain with a cloth simulation. However, the top part is still straight and I want this to be in a circular shape. I tried moving it along a BezierCircle, but that didn't do it for me.
As can be seen in the second picture, I want the pink line to be in the circular shape of the yellow line.
How can I change the upper part of a straight cloth into a circular shape?
Do I need to do this while animating or can I move this along a circular curve?
Here is the file:



If I try it with a rectangular shaped cloth, it works fine with BezierCircle.

Here is the file with the curve: 
File Oct 23: 

You can try with the Curve or the Simple Deform modifier:
First create a gradient vertex group at the top with the Gradient brush:

Give a Curve modifier to your curtain, select the vertex group so that only the top is affected. I had to align the curtain on X to make it work fine though because I was a bit lost with its orientation:

Second solution, create an empty and give your curtain a Simple Deform modifier, Bend mode, with the empty as Origin, Z axis and select the vertex group. Now move the empty on X and Y until you have something circular, it will be hard to fit the exact circular shape but you'll scale the top later in Edit mode with the Proportional Editing option on:

File: 
For your current file:
In Edit mode rotate the mesh so that it is aligned with the X axis. In Object mode, right click > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry:

Switch the curve to Edit mode, rotate it 180 on Y:

Put the origin at this vertex location:


is there any other way? I am not sure if that has the result that I am looking for. I added another picture to show that it works perfectly fine with a rectangular shaped cloth. Not sure why it doesn't work with this one.

Yes you can do it with a Curve modifier, just select the vertex group so that only the top is affected, please see my edit

I cannot make it work.. I am getting a different result with that unfortunately. It sort of twists the top part of the cloth.

Please share the file with the Curve modifier

Added a second file to the question

Here is your file, corrected, I had to correct the vertex group, align the object with the X axis, apply the rotation, rotate the curve in Edit mode, change the circle's origin position, etc, now it seems good? 

It does seem good. Can you maybe explain this further in detail? I would like to be able to do this myself :)

I've edited, I hope you understand everything?

I am not sure if I understand everything. Couple of questions:

Why would I have to  align the object with X axis, if the rotation XY is already at 0degrees? How do you align it then?
And why would I have to change the curve radius to 1 and do a SX -1?
My gradient in weight painting is not circular like yours, is that a problem? Do you also add another vertex group so you have two or do you delete the first vertex group?


Adding to the align object. If I do Object > Transform > Align object > Choose X, nothing happens?

Hello could you please share your last version? I've shared the file btw, maybe take a look?

I think the problem is that I don't really understand what I am doing in order to get the curtain to be in that circular shape on top. I added the latest file at the bottom of the question.

I've re-dited my answer, please check

Okay that works, can you maybe explain a couple of things?

Why does it have to align to the x-axis?
Why do I have to rotate the curve on Y 180 degrees?
Why does the mean radius of the circle need to be 1? Is that sort of the same as scaling?


I do notice I don't have a lot of control over scaling the top, but I guess that's related to this way of doing it. I also notice if I want to duplicate and rotate it, I have to apply the curve modifier, so it is a destructive method. I am just getting into geometry nodes. Do you think this would be easier with that? Well, not necessarily easier, but do you think I might have more control with geometry nodes?

It's better to have it aligned on an axis as it will get deformed according to the axis you'll determine (by default it is X). If the Radius of a vertex is not 1 the object will get deformed (il will bloat), it can happen if you scale the curve and apply the scale. If you want to duplicate your object, also duplicate the curve. I don't know enough about Geonodes, so I can't answer.

Thank you so much! Very clear!
